# How to store and compress data for real time data logging?

Tags: database, input, signals, real-time

When developing software that records input signals (numbers) in real time, how can this data be best stored and compressed? Would an SQL engine be good for this, permitting fast data mining in the future, or are there other data formats that would be suitable or compressed enough for upto 1000 data samples per second?

I don't mind building in VC++ but ideas applicable to C# would be ideal.

Comment: 1000 data samples per second, but for how many seconds ?

Comment: Think "forever"! My client says I really have no control over that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say without more info, such as, what is the source, will you be needing to query the stored data, and so on.

But for 1000 samples/sec, you should propably look at holding a few seconds of data in memory, and then writing them out in bulk to persistent storage on another thread. (Multi-processor machine recommended).

If you decide to do it via a managed language, keep the same data structure around for keeping the samples - so that the GC does not need to collect memory too often. You can get marginally better performance by using pointers and the unsafe keyword (provides direct access to the memory structure and eliminates bounds checking code for arrays).

I don't know how much CPU time is needed for you to collect each sample; and how time-critical it is to read each sample at a specified time (will they be buffered in the device you are reading from ?). If the sampling is time-critical, you have 1 ms per sample; and then you probably cannot afford the risk of the garbage collector kicking in, as it will block your thread for some time. In this case, I would go for an unmanaged approach.

SQL Server would easily be able to hold your data, or you could write them to a file. It mostly depends on what you need to do with the data at a later time. I don't know how much data each sample is, but let's assume it is 8 bytes. Then you have 8000 bytes per second to write of raw data - perhaps you have some overhead, so it could be 10 kB/s. Most storage mechanisms I can think of will be able to write data at this speed. Just make sure to write on another thread than the one that are doing the sampling.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at time-series databases, rather than relational. These will be optimised to deal with the sort of data and usage you're considering.

[Kx](http://kx.com/) is a popular choice, as is [Fame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAME_%28database%29).